# Automatic refactor of sonar qube rule Private fields only used as local variables in methods should become local variables

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-cleanup, automated-refactoring

We are using SonarQube Server for a big java application. (IDE = Eclipse + SonarLint plugin). Rule [Private fields only used as local variables in methods should become local variables](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1450) is violated in about 6000 cases. Is there an automatic method of refactoring this issue?

Example:

Actual situation:

```
public class A {
  private JLabel lblText;
  ...
  public void foo() {
    lblText = new JLabel();
    lblText.setText("Text");
    mainPanel.addComponent(lblText, 2, 1);
    ...
  }
...
}
```

After refactor:

```
public class A {
  ...
  public void foo() {
    JLabel lblText = new JLabel();
    lblText.setText("Text");
    mainPanel.addComponent(lblText, 2, 1);
    ...
  }
...
}
```

Can I achieve this automatically? It would take a huge amount of time to do 6000 cases manually.